How can I calculate the throughput from Vivado HLS performance summary?
I have PYNQ-Z2 board, and I am trying to accelerate canny edge detection.
I faced issues with the block design from the place of IP core. Its blocking the processing.
This is the code I am referring to
https://github.com/medalotte/HLS-canny-edge-detection
This is the performance summary.
enter image description here
I want to estimate the throughput for 600 frame
In case someone is experienced
this is the block diagram:
I am using the base overlay and insert it inside the video block and then inside the hdmi-in block. I have no idea why it is blocking.
enter image description here
But my main question is: How can I calculate the throughput from Vivado HLS performance summary for 600 frames so I can compare it to PS and estimate the speed up.
The clock frequency is 142MHz
